# How to handle ipfs credentials?

Tags: ipfs

Is it okay to share the secret access key for ipfs upload (e.g. crust network or 4everland) with the client frontend? It's also possible to delete the key from the ipfs service provider. To hide the secret access key one needs a centralized server which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

With 4EVER Security Token Service API one can pass in custom policy for better access control, which are fully compatible with AWS S3 STS!

https://docs.4everland.org/storage/bucket/4ever-security-token-service-api